# What identifies a "Dota2" item in Steam?

Tags: steam, steam-web-api

In the Dota2 schema the items are assigned a "defindex", which seems to be a unique id. 
I used the following call to get the schema.
http://api.steampowered.com/IEconItems_570/GetSchema/v0001/?key=XXXX

However, when one reads a user's backpack from steam, items with the same "defindex" have different qualities.
Here the call used to get the items of a user
http://api.steampowered.com/IEconItems_570/GetPlayerItems/v0001?key=XXX&SteamID=YYY

For instance, here is the definition of the item with defindex = 4122 in the GetSchema call.

> ```
> {
>             "name": "Seafarer's Shoes",
>             "defindex": 4122,
>             "item_class": "dota_item_wearable",
>             "item_type_name": "#DOTA_WearableType_Shoes",
>             "item_name": "#DOTA_Item_Seafarers_Shoes",
>             "item_description": "#DOTA_Item_Desc_Seafarers_Shoes",
>             "proper_name": false,
>             "item_quality": 4,
>             "image_inventory": "econ/items/kunkka/legs_admirableadmiral",
>             "min_ilevel": 1,
>             "max_ilevel": 1,
>             "image_url": "http://cdn.dota2.com/apps/570/icons/econ/items/kunkka/legs_admirableadmiral.e679e41f99350070d812fe5cd57acda4c83a99a0.png",
>             "image_url_large": "http://cdn.dota2.com/apps/570/icons/econ/items/kunkka/legs_admirableadmiral_large.5a9acb228f9cae6c2d6cb1199ad2bba2f54955d6.png",
>             "item_set": "kunkka_admirable_admiral",
>             "capabilities": {
>                 "nameable": true,
>                 "can_craft_mark": true,
>                 "can_be_restored": true,
>                 "strange_parts": true,
>                 "paintable_unusual": true,
>                 "autograph": true,
>                 "can_consume": true,
>                 "can_have_sockets": true
>             }
>         },    {
>             "name": "Seafarer's Shoes",
>             "defindex": 4122,
>             "item_class": "dota_item_wearable",
>             "item_type_name": "#DOTA_WearableType_Shoes",
>             "item_name": "#DOTA_Item_Seafarers_Shoes",
>             "item_description": "#DOTA_Item_Desc_Seafarers_Shoes",
>             "proper_name": false,
>             "item_quality": 4,
>             "image_inventory": "econ/items/kunkka/legs_admirableadmiral",
>             "min_ilevel": 1,
>             "max_ilevel": 1,
>             "image_url": "http://cdn.dota2.com/apps/570/icons/econ/items/kunkka/legs_admirableadmiral.e679e41f99350070d812fe5cd57acda4c83a99a0.png",
>             "image_url_large": "http://cdn.dota2.com/apps/570/icons/econ/items/kunkka/legs_admirableadmiral_large.5a9acb228f9cae6c2d6cb1199ad2bba2f54955d6.png",
>             "item_set": "kunkka_admirable_admiral",
>             "capabilities": {
>                 "nameable": true,
>                 "can_craft_mark": true,
>                 "can_be_restored": true,
>                 "strange_parts": true,
>                 "paintable_unusual": true,
>                 "autograph": true,
>                 "can_consume": true,
>                 "can_have_sockets": true
>             }
>         },
> ```

And here are two instances of items, both with defindex = 4122 in a user's backpack:

> ```
>  {
>             "id": xxxx,
>             "original_id": yyyy,
>             "defindex": 4122,
>             "level": 1,
>             "quality": 4,
>             "inventory": 157,
>             "quantity": 1
>         },
>         {
>             "id": zzzz,
>             "original_id": wwww,
>             "defindex": 4122,
>             "level": 1,
>             "quality": 12,
>             "inventory": 172,
>             "quantity": 1,
>             "attributes": [
>                 {
>                     "defindex": 185,
>                     "value": 1374925866,
>                     "float_value": 130837463040
>                 },
>                 {
>                     "defindex": 312,
>                     "value": 95566398,
>                     "float_value": 1.6760434356454931e-035,
>                     "account_info": {
>                         "steamid": fffff,
>                         "personaname": "fly fly"
>                     }
>                 },
>                 {
>                     "defindex": 313,
>                     "value": 86741690,
>                     "float_value": 8.0673307729579346e-036,
>                     "account_info": {
>                         "steamid": ggggg,
>                         "personaname": "???????"
>                     }
>                 },
>                 {
>                     "defindex": 315,
>                     "value": 0,
>                     "float_value": 0
>                 },
>                 {
>                     "defindex": 316,
>                     "value": 0,
>                     "float_value": 0
>                 },
>                 {
>                     "defindex": 317,
>                     "value": 2,
>                     "float_value": 2.8025969286496341e-045
>                 },
>                 {
>                     "defindex": 318,
>                     "value": 254535695,
>                     "float_value": 8.4756437840051154e-030
>                 },
>                 {
>                     "defindex": 320,
>                     "value": 1155752210,
>                     "float_value": 1819.033447265625
>                 },
>                 {
>                     "defindex": 389,
>                     "value": 59,
>                     "float_value": 8.2676609395164207e-044
>                 },
>                 {
>                     "defindex": 396,
>                     "value": 1115,
>                     "float_value": 1.562447787722171e-042
>                 },
>                 {
>                     "defindex": 397,
>                     "value": 1073741824,
>                     "float_value": 2
>                 }
>             ]
> ```

```
        },
```

You may notice that the two items in the user's backpack have different 
qualities (4 and 12 respectively, probably due to the second item having attributes that refer to other items.

The question is what does it take to define a user's item precisely enough for trading purposes?

It is not sufficient to say I am offering an item with defindex=4122.  From the above example it seems that I need to say: "I am offering an item with defindex=4122 and quality = 12."  But is that enough?  There may be other characteristics one needs to specify to accurately define a Dota2 item.

Does anyone know where to find such information/documentation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have made two key elements of your item instances anonymous to post this question. The elements `id` and `original_id` uniquely identify a specific item.

`original_id` is the id that the object is given the first time it is granted to a user. This id does not change, ever, over the course of the item's life. The `id` field changes every time the item is modified, or changes ownership (ie traded).

Using the `original_id`, an item's history can be tracked as it goes through the economy. This is how backpack sites have historical ownership data. If you are trading, the `id` is sufficient, since it will not change unless the user does something to modify it (ie: in the TF2 world, add a name tag or paint it). This `id` is also what the [SteamBot](https://github.com/Jessecar96/SteamBot/) project uses to complete trades.

One very important note (at least in the TF2 world): There are very rare instances where an `id` can be duplicated. These are the result of exploits that existed and were utilized before being patched (at this moment there are no known duplication exploits) or the result of Steam support's intervention in scam attempts. I believe Steam support has altered their policy of simply duplicating the item to instead regranting a new item, but I am unable to find reliable citations.

*Edit based on question in comment*
My experience with DOTA is limited, but I can provide an answer based on TF2 and looking at the schema layout and backpack layout make some educated guesses. The two fields that can be most easily modified in TF2 are `quality` and the `attributes` list.

Quality can be modified by applying Strange Parts, and upgrading kill streak kits. The attributes can be modified by applying cosmetic items to the item (name tag, description tag, paint, etc).

The user has no control over the two different ID fields mentioned above, the level (which in most cases is a random number anyway), the quantity or the value in the inventory field.

Much of this information is from [here](http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/WebAPI/GetPlayerItems).

Comment: Agreed, and apologies for making the ids anonymous.

Comment: Here is another way to phrase the question: "items" in the Dota2 published schema base their description, image and some characteristics on the defindex.I mean, an id in the user's backpack does not contain the image or the description of the  item; it relies on the Schema to get that info. Yet other 
characteristics of ids that share the same defindex may vary when looking at individual ids in users' backpacks. Quality is one of them. The question then is which characteristics are unique (or locked) to a defindex and which are allowed to vary as users fiddle with their items.@Andy

Answer (score 0):

'defindex' is a key that represents a specific item within a specific array.

For example 396 exists twice in the schema:

Once for "Shadow Demon's Cape" and another for "event time". But they are in separate arrays ("items" for "Shadow Demon's Cape" and the "attributes" contains "event time")

The schema provides information on the "attributes" these are in the schema under the 'attribute' array. An item with quality **"tournament": 12** has tournament related attributes.:

```
    {
            "name": "tournament killer id",
            "defindex": 312,
            "attribute_class": "tournament_killer_id",
            "description_string": "#Attrib_TournamentKillerID",
            "description_format": "value_is_account_id",
            "effect_type": "positive",
            "hidden": true,
            "stored_as_integer": true
    }

{
                "name": "tournament id",
                "defindex": 315,
                "attribute_class": "tournament_id",
                "description_string": "#Attrib_TournamentID",
                "description_format": "value_is_additive",
                "effect_type": "positive",
                "hidden": true,
                "stored_as_integer": true
            }
```

Quality is significant as some qualities are not trade-able see: http://dota2.gamepedia.com/Quality

item_quality corresponds to this array in the schema:

```
"qualities": {
            "normal": 0,
            "genuine": 1,
            "vintage": 2,
            "unusual": 3,
            "unique": 4,
            "community": 5,
            "developer": 6,
            "selfmade": 7,
            "customized": 8,
            "strange": 9,
            "completed": 10,
            "haunted": 11,
            "tournament": 12,
            "favored": 13,
            "ascendant": 14,
            "autographed": 15,
            "legacy": 16,
            "exalted": 17,
            "frozen": 18,
            "corrupted": 19,
            "lucky": 20
        }
```